# how to count number of files in a sub-folder having a specific pattern?

Tags: grep

I have installed ubuntu as part a college course and I would like to familiarise further with the command line.

I have ton's of text files which I would like to search for specific phrase but I don't know out to count them.

Is there a direct way to do that?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the direct way but I do it like below.

```
grep -rl <pattern> <folder>  | wc -l
```

use the manual page to identify the purpose if each option.